# About Embeds in Discord (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I'm currently coding a bot for discord, but I'm facing a problem with embeds. So I want to send a Embed that shows an certain amount of object properties as a Inline Field, so I thought about making a for loop and put the .addField in it, something like this.

```
let object = {
  "name1" : "value1",
  "name2" : "value2",
  "name3" : "value3"
}

const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  //... other embeds elements
  for (let i of object) {
    .addField("Inline Field", i, true) 

    //So for each property of the object created above it will add
    // a Inline Field to the Embed with the value of i, the variable that holds the properties of the
    // object.
}
```

The only problem with this is that it doesn't work. So I'm asking here for alternatives ways of solving my problem. Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the output in Discord?

Comment: do `exampleEmbed.addField(...)` instead of `.addField(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @secretlyrice suggested in the comments, instead of doing `.addField(...)`, referencing the embed variable works, like `exampleEmbed.addField(...)`.